Firebase Realtime Database Pagination in Recyclerview
I am implementing a paging method in my code, however when recyclerview reaches the last item, the code duplicates the same items loaded at the beginning, in this case it is not loading the new items
Here below are the methods I'm working on to upload images and text
ProgressBar progressBar1;
RecyclerView recyclerView;
private UserRVAdapter mAdapter;
final int mPostsPerPage = 5;
boolean mIsLoading = false;


recyclerView.addOnScrollListener(new RecyclerView.OnScrollListener() {
  @Override
  public void onScrolled(@NonNull RecyclerView recyclerView, int dx, int dy) {
      super.onScrolled(recyclerView, dx, dy);

      int lastVisiblesItems = layoutManager.findLastVisibleItemPosition();
      int firstVisiblesItems = layoutManager.findFirstVisibleItemPosition();

      if (!recyclerView.canScrollVertically(1) && dy > 0) { //scrolled to BOTTOM
          Toast.makeText(getContext(), "fetch data", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
          getUsers(mAdapter.getLastItemId());
          mIsLoading = true;
          progressBar1.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
      } else if (lastVisiblesItems > 2  && dy < 0) {

      }
  }
});

void:
   private void getUsers(String nodeId) {
          Query query;
        
          if (nodeId == null)
              query = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference()
                      .child("Data")
                      .orderByKey()
                      .limitToFirst(mPostsPerPage);
          else
              query = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference()
                      .child("Data")
                      .orderByKey()
                      .startAt(nodeId)
                      .limitToFirst(mPostsPerPage);
        
          query.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
              @Override
              public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                  UserModel user;
                  List<UserModel> userModels = new ArrayList<>();
                  for (DataSnapshot userSnapshot : dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {
                      userModels.add(userSnapshot.getValue(UserModel.class));
                  }
        
                  mAdapter.addAll(userModels);
                  mIsLoading = false;
                  progressBar1.setVisibility(View.GONE);
              }
        
              @Override
              public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError databaseError) {
                  mIsLoading = false;
              }
          });
        }


Why not using Paging v3 library?
